# Пути в PHP

Tags: cron, php

Скрипт запускается с крона, в скрипте получаю данные из текстового файла, который лежит рядом со скриптом (test.txt).

Вопрос, какой путь нужно указывать в скрипте, чтобы крон правильно работал?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это очень правильный вопрос, потому что на относительный путь в кроне нельзя полагаться никогда, он задается даже отдельно от того пути, по которому переходит свежезашедший юзер.

В контексте PHP все, все до единого пути должны быть абсолютными вне зависимости от типа вызова; это а) не очень сложно и б) спасает от последующего геморроя. Конкретно в данной ситуации достаточно использовать конструкцию `__DIR__ . '/test.txt'` (винда нормально сожрет такой слеш, хотя для чистоты можно использовать `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`).

Если в скрипт тем или иным способом попадает относительный путь, то чем раньше он будет сконвертирован в абсолютный, тем лучше. В случае, если цель (директория или файл) существует, то для этого можно использовать функцию `realpath()`; она не работает с url wrappers, но это будет интересовать только когда-нибудь потом в разрезе тестирвоания.

Answer (score 1):

Эмн...
Крон запустил скрипт и всё - дальше сам.
Взять данные на PHP можно как-то так: `$data = file_get_contents('test.txt')`.

Comment: @TheDoctor, я имел ввиду пути относительные и абсолютные, нужно ли их использовать для крона

Comment: Хм... Ладно.  
Всё зависит от того, где находится то, что ты запускать хочешь.  
Но абсолютные почти всегда лучше ИМХО.